# Proof of $\hat{\mathrm{O}}$ta's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, closed-graph

I'm trying to prove $\hat{\mathrm{O}}$ta's theorem :

> Let $A$ be a closed operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and $\overline{\mathcal{D}(A)}=H$. Suppose that $A\mathcal{D}(A)\subset \mathcal{D}(A)$ and the set $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} |\ \mathcal{R}(\lambda I-A) \mathrm{\ is \ closed}\}$ is unbounded. Then $A$ is bounded.

I have a problem with the following part of the proof of this theorem :

Let $\hat H:=\left(\mathcal{D}(A),\|\cdot\|_A\right)$, where $\|x\|_A^2=\|x\|^2+\|Ax\|^2$. How to prove that if $|z|>\|A\|_{\hat H}$ (where $A:\hat H\rightarrow \hat H$ we treat as a closed operator on $\hat H$) then $\mathcal{D}(A)=\mathcal{R}(zI-A)$ ?

Comment: How do we know that $\|A\|_{\hat H}<\infty ?$ ?

Comment: Since $A:\hat H \rightarrow \hat H$ is closed we can use closed graph theorem to deduce that $A\in B(\hat H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in your comment, $\hat{A} : \hat{H}\rightarrow\hat{H}$ is bounded. Therefore $\hat{A}-\lambda I$ is invertible for $|\lambda| > \|\hat{A}\|_{\hat{H}}$, which guarantees that $\mathcal{R}(\hat{A}-\lambda I)=\hat{H}$ for such $\lambda$, or $(A-\lambda I)\mathcal{D}(A)=\mathcal{D}(A)$ for such $\lambda$.

Comment: Why invertibility quarantees that $\mathcal{R}(\lambda I−\hat A)=\hat H $? We only know that operator $\lambda I−\hat A$ is injective. It is surjective onto an image, but why the image must be a whole space ? (In the definition of invertilibity we have that if $A:\mathcal{D}(A)→\mathcal{R}(A)\subset H$ is invertible then $A^{−1}$ is well defined on $\mathcal{R}(A)$, not necessarily on $H$ ).

Comment: @mikis : Invertibility means you have a bijection. Did you study the resolvent series for a bounded operator $B$ on a Banach space? There you find that $(B-\lambda I)^{-1} =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}B^{n}$ is a left and right inverse for $|\lambda| > \|B\|$. You can verify $-(B-\lambda I)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}B^{n}=I$ under those circumstances.

Comment: Oh, right.... Thanks!